# Ember.js data - basic adapter does not implement findAll method?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

With the basic adapter

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.BasicAdapter'
});
```

I have:

> 'Uncaught Adapter is either null or does not implement `findAll` method'.

And indeed there is no `findAll` method in the `basicAdapter` (I did make sure the adapter isn't null). I am using all the newest version of ember and ember data (build from master for ember, from master and basic-adapter branch for emberjs).

Is this not implemented yet or did I miss something ?
Since I'm beginning with ember I'm not too confident to submit a pull request, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `sync` object. For example:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
        author: DS.attr('string'),
        read: DS.attr('boolen')
    });

    App.Post.sync = {
        query: function (id, process) {
            console.log('find query for Post', arguments);

            $.getJSON('/path/to/API/').then(function (posts) {
                process(posts.map(function (post) {
                    return {
                        author: post.author,
                        read: post.is_read
                    };
                })).load();

                console.log('got posts', posts);
            });
        }
    };
```

Then associate model with route:

```
    App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log('Post route');

        return App.Post.find({});
    }
});
```

Once you visit `post` route in your app you should be good. `{}` in `find()` is important.